# Spark Dataset - read CSV and write empty output

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have an input file `test-reading.csv`

```
id,sku,price
"100002701--425370728",100002701,12159
"100002701--510892030",100002701,11021
"100002701-235195215",100002701,12330
"100002701-110442364",100002701,9901
"100002701-1963746094",100002701,11243
```

I wrote following source code in order to have a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem I'm facing.

There is a `ReadingRecord` class used to read the CSV file and a `WritingRecord` used to write the output. Incidentally now they are almost identical but in the real program were quite different because they represent input and output structure.

The remaining code starts Spark, read the CSV, map `ReadingRecord` to `WritingRecord` and write an output CSV.

The question is: why if I uncomment the `for` loop into the `flatMapGroups` method this Spark program stops to write the CSV output?

```
case class ReadingRecord(var id: String, var sku: Integer, var price: Integer) {
  def toWritingRecord(): WritingRecord = {
    new WritingRecord(this.id, this.sku, this.price)
  }
}

case class WritingRecord(var id: String, var sku: Integer, var price: Integer)

object ReadingRecordEncoders {
  implicit def ReadingRecordEncoder: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[ReadingRecord] =
    org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[ReadingRecord]
}

object WritingTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local[8]")
      .setAppName("writing-test")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "1gb")
      .set("spark.num.executors", "8")
      .set("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "120")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    import ReadingRecordEncoders._

    val data = spark.read.option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("test-reading.csv")
      .map(r => {
        println(r)
        new ReadingRecord(r(0).asInstanceOf[String], r(1).asInstanceOf[Integer], r(2).asInstanceOf[Integer])
      }).groupByKey(r1 => r1.sku)

    val data1 = data.flatMapGroups((a: Integer, b: Iterator[ReadingRecord]) => {
      var list = new ArrayList[ReadingRecord]
      try {
        //        for (o <- b) {
        //          list.add(o)
        //        }
      } finally {
        list.clear()
        list = null
      }

      b.map(f => f.toWritingRecord)
    })

    data1.printSchema()

    data1.write
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .save("output.csv")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the commented out code included, you are trying to reuse the `Iterator` `b`.  An `Iterator` is modified when it is used:

> It is of particular importance to note that, unless stated otherwise, *one should never use an iterator after calling a method on it*.

See [the Iterator documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/Iterator.html).